# Why R change Persian character to Arabic one?

Tags: r

When I use the Persian locale, R changes "ی" to "ي".

```r
Sys.setlocale(category = "LC_ALL", locale = "persian")

 a = "ی"
 print(a)
[1] "ي"
```

It makes many problems.

#### Update 1 :

[image]

Interestingly, when I enter `ی` on the Persian keyboard in `RGui`,  and it appears as  `ي`

[image]

Comment: At least for me  on R 4.0.0 with windows 64 bit that doesn't happen - you may need to include the output of `sessionInfo()` to give a clue what is going on

Comment: I think this is related to this question:
https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2014-February/370760.html
in short:
There are a lot of places in R where it converts strings to the local 
encoding, perhaps too many.  (Duncan Murdoch)

Answer (score 0):

It is now a known Rstudio bug.
https://github.com/rstudio/rstudio/issues/9437